# In tf.layers.conv2d, with use_bias=True, are the biases tied or untied?

Tags: python, tensorflow

One more question:

If they are tied biases, how can I implement untied biases?

I am using tensorflow 1.10.0 in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tied biases** is used in `tf.layers.conv2d`.

If you want united biases, just turn off `use_bias` and create bias variable manually with `tf.Variable` or `tf.get_variable` same shape with following feature map, finally sum them up.